# In a multilinear regression, does the usage of White standard errors always correct for heteroscedasticity?

Tags: multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

I've calculated a multilinear regression. When testing the assumptions of linear regression, I've come to understand that my model violates the assumption of homoscedasticity (as shown with a Breusch-Pagan test). I've been searching for ways to palliate for this violation, and I've come upon the usage of White standard errors (sandwich method).

1- Does the usage of White standard errors guarantee correction for heteroscedasticity?

2- Is there a method I should be using to verify that heteroscedasticity has been accounted for after having used the sandwich method?

3- What are the implications of reporting White standard errors instead of the initial standard errors? Are there any differences in the interpretation of the multilinear model?

Comment: What independent method would show the correct results? Minimally, use of Eicker-Huber-White-robust standard errors allows a comparison with traditional standard errors. If they are quite different, the implication is that heteroscedasticity is a big deal. But the coefficient estimates are the same. The only difference for interpretation is for interpreting lack of fit and whether model specification should be rethought. Also, those results can't tell you whether a quite different approach would be a better idea, such as a generalised linear model and/or transformation of  variables.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You've helped answer many of my questions.

I'm extrapolating from your answer, but if the White robust standard errors seem not so different from the traditional errors, would heteroscedasticity not be a "big deal"? In other words, could I assume that presenting my multilinear model with White robust standard errors to an audience would be adequate? I've tried transforming my model (Box-Cox) with no success, and I'd rather not tackle generalized linear models for practical reasons. Thanks again.

Comment: Correct in that similar results for standard errors imply that heteroscedasticity is not much of a worry, with nothing else said. But otherwise there can be no guarantee that your model is adequate and we can't comment on your audience. Any plain linear regression model, or yours in particular, might be a bad idea. But I guess you know that, so I am not really sure what you are asking. By the way, "multilinear" may be a standard term in your field, but even "multiple" is fading away as a qualifier. Most regression models involve several predictors.